# Rewarded Ads – Disallowed Rewarded Implementation

Tags: admob, google-ad-manager

How to solve this.
I have added a notification when user will see ads. Now where is the problem. My code is here.

```
public class AdMobAds {
    private Context context;
    public AdMobAds(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    private final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-9323045181924630/1652450256";
     private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
     public String button = "";
    public void loadRewardedAd() {

        if (rewardedAd == null) {
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            RewardedAd.load(
                    context,
                    AD_UNIT_ID,
                    adRequest,
                    new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                            // Handle the error.
                            //Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                            rewardedAd = null;
                            loadRewardedAd();
                            //MainActivity.this.isLoading = false;
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "onAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                            AdMobAds.this.rewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                            button = "ON";
                            //Log.d(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                            //MainActivity.this.isLoading = false;
                            //Toast.makeText(context, "onAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    public void showRewardedVideo() {

        if (rewardedAd == null) {
            //Log.d("TAG", "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
            //Toast.makeText(context, "ads not work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadRewardedAd();
            return;
        }else{
            rewardedAd.show((Activity) context, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Mining Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }


        rewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(
                new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Called when ad is shown.
                        //Log.d("TAG", "onAdShowedFullScreenContent");
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "onAdShowedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                        // Called when ad fails to show.
                        //Log.d("TAG", "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent");
                        // Don't forget to set the ad reference to null so you
                        // don't show the ad a second time.
                        rewardedAd = null;
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                        // Called when ad is dismissed.
                        // Don't forget to set the ad reference to null so you
                        // don't show the ad a second time.
                        rewardedAd = null;
                        button = "";
                        //Log.d("TAG", "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent");
                        //Toast.makeText(context, "onAdDismissedFullScreenContent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Preload the next rewarded ad.
                        loadRewardedAd();
                    }
                });

    }

 }
```

What I can do now?

When user want to run a ads they will get a dialog for ads notification. Now they limit my ads. I don't understand what I can do. I knocked in admob support community they do mot give any reply.

Comment: Who is "they"? did "they" give a reason for the limit"?

Comment: No, They don’t. Just showing, invalid traffic